# JS equivalent of PHP function to find cookies

Tags: javascript, php, regex, cookies

I have a small shopping cart to use with PHP in WordPress, but now I'm implementing it to be used in a site with AJAX.

I have a PHP function that finds some cookies that tell me what the user has put in the shopping cart, however, since now I'm loading the product info into the same div according to user selection, that function with PHP is no longer useful and need to do it with JS or JQuery in order to be updated every time the user changes to another product.

The function in PHP is:

```
function in_cart($post_id){
$found = false;
if(!empty($_COOKIE['cart'])){
    foreach ($_COOKIE ['cart'] as $c) {
        if ($c ['id'] == $post_id)
            $found = $c;
    }
}   
return $found;
```

}

The cookies are called "cart[0][id]" and "cart[0][quantity]" where the "0" increments depending on how many products there are, and with that function I can just run trough all instances of a cookie that starts as "cart", but I can't seem to replicate that loop in JS.

I tried to do it with a regex expression in order to allow any number inside the first set og brackets, but it won't work (I'm quite new to JS so not sure if I did it correctly).

Does anyone have a suggestion?

UPDATE:
This was my last attempt to use regex:

```
var nums = /^[0-9]+$/;
function readCookie(c_name)
{
var c_value = document.cookie;
var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  }
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_value = null;
  }
else
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
  var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
  if (c_end == -1)
  {
c_end = c_value.length;
}
c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
}
return c_value;
}
cart = readCookie("cart["+ nums +"][id]");
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: You can simply use `substr` instead of regexes.

Comment: Added my last attempt on the post...

Answer (score 1):

Please see the excellent [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) on how to access cookies in javascript, they even provide a full implementation for reading/writing cookie values. In a nutshell, cookies can be accessed as attribute of the document: `document.cookie`. That attribute has all the cookies belonging to your domain stored as string (e.g.: `foo=bar;baz=bizz`). To access an individual element you would have to come up with some regex magic, thus the link to the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie). ;-)

The solution there let's you set/get/check/delete cookies very comfortable, e.g.

```
docCookies.setItem("foo", "bar");
docCookies.getItem("foo"); // bar
docCookies.hasItem("foo"); // true
docCookies.removeItem("foo");
```

Btw, if you're using jQuery, there's a very nice [plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Comment: I actually did run across that page and helped me understand cookies in JS, however my issue is that I cannot go through all cookies that are called "cart[*any number*][id]". But I can read all cookies or get one in particular, for example if I search for  "cart[0][id]" I can get it, but I need to know if there may be more than one, ie  "cart[1][id]",  "cart[2][id]", etc.